# Longtable starts on the next page while there is a lot of space to use on the current page

Tags: longtable, overleaf

I have an issue with longtables where it starts on the next page while there is a lot of space to use on the current page. I tried multiple solutions but in vain. I don't know what I should do now. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[left=3.81cm, right=2.54cm, top=3.175cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\hbadness=99999 

\begin{document}

    \section{Proposed storage solutions}
    Based on the current packaging and storage issues the following solutions were proposed after brainstorming:

    \begin{longtable}[!h]
    \centering
    \hspace*{-4cm}%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{|p{0.2\linewidth}|p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.1\linewidth}|}
        \hline
        % HEADER ROW
        \textbf{Solution} & \textbf{Specifications} & \textbf{Pros} & \textbf{Cons} & \textbf{Total   cost} \\ \hline

        % FIRST ROW
        \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=60mm]{images/myLboro.png}}

        & 
        \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
             \item[] Configuration: Vertical
             \item[] Stability: Tension clamp with pressure plate
             \item[] Dimensions: 48’’x 40 x 65’’
             \item[] Capacity: 661 pounds
        \end{itemize}

        & 
        \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
             \item[] Easy to assemble/ dismantle the rack.
             \item[] Space-saving compared to storing doors in crates.
             \item[] Cheaper than other A-frame racks
        \end{itemize}
 
        & 
        \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
             \item[] Not stackable
             \item[] Space-saving compared to storing doors in crates.
             \item[] Cheaper than other A-frame racks
        \end{itemize}
        
        &  \\ \hline

        % SECOND ROW
        \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=60mm]{images/myLboro.png}}

        &
        \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
            \item[] configuration: Vertical 
            \item[] Dimensions: At least one-third of the product height should rest against the divider. The V-Divider depth dimension= 4 ft
        \end{itemize}
 
        & 
        \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
            \item[] Bulk doors stored vertically within a bay.
            \item[] Facilitates one part picking.
            \item[] Cheaper than buying new racks.
        \end{itemize}
        
        & 
        \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
            \item[] Add door fixtures to secure doors at the bottom to timber decking or rack mesh.
            \item[] Dividers to divide 8 different P/N.
            \item[] Labeling locations per dividers.
        \end{itemize}
        
        &  \\ \hline
        
        % THIRD ROW
        \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=60mm]{images/myLboro.png}}

        & 
        \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
            \item[] Configuration: Horizontally on the bars 
            \item[] Dimensions:16"W x 26"L x 24"H 
        \end{itemize}
        & 
        \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
            \item[] Capacity: 7,500 LBS
            \item[] Stackable up to five units high
            \item[] Unit cost: 115.96 \$
            \item[] Space needed per unit: 4.3 sq,ft
        \end{itemize}
        &  
        \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
            \item[] NO CONS
        \end{itemize}
        
        &  \\ \hline
 
        \end{tabular}
        
    \hspace*{-3cm}%
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: longtable is not a replacement for table but for tabular. So don't put a tabular in it. See the documentation about examples how to use longtable correctly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should not bested `tabular` table in long table. Remove it and move it specification to `longtable`. BTW, your table is wider than available ˛text width.

Comment: The table is to taller than available space in the page . Consider to use  for example `\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=30mm]{...` and perhaps a landscape page.

Comment: BTW, [!h] is not a lo.ngtable option.  Only [c] [l] and [r].

Comment: do not ignore errors `! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\centering): \`c' used.`  because you have not specified any `{ccc}` columns. After such an error it is no point asking about the pdf which is not intended to be usable, just a debugging aid.

Comment: on an unrelated note, you  should use `\slash ` instead of `/ `  in row 1 col 3. The `assemble\slash dismantle` will split at the slash if needs be and not have the extraneous space if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As mentioned in @Ulrike Fisher's comment, `longtable` is not a replacement for `table` but for `tabular`.
- Your table is wider than the prescribed `\texwidth`, consequently, it pounds out of the right page border.
- Simple solution is instead of `longtable` to use `tabularray` package and its `longtblr` environment for long tables and its `X` column type for the second, third and fourth column.

**Edit:**

- Removed table caption(s),
- font size in the table is reduced to `\small`,
- to the table is added a fourth row for showing how `longtnblr` break between pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, demo]{report}  % in real document remove "demo"
\usepackage[hmargin={3.81cm, 2.54cm}, top=3.175cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export,
            demo]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\section{Proposed storage solutions}
Based on the current packaging and storage issues, the following solutions were proposed after brainstorming:

\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} % <---
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{\scriptsize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
%
\setkeys{Gin}{width=20mm, height=60mm}
\begin{longtblr}{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {c *{3}{X[h, l]} c},
                  colsep  = {4pt},
                  column{1} = {colsep=3pt},
                  row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries, c, m}, 
                  row{2-Z} = {belowsep+=-4pt},
                  rowhead = 1,
                  }        
Solution    
    & Specifications    
        & Pros  
            & Cons  
                & {Total\\ cost}    \\
% table body
% FIRST ROW
\includegraphics{images/myLboro.png}
    & {Configuration: Vertical\\
       Stability: Tension clamp with pressure plate\\
       Dimensions: \qtyproduct{48 x 40 x 65}{''}
       Capacity: \qty{661}{pounds}}
        & {Easy to assemble/ dismantle the rack.\\
           Space-saving compared to storing doors in crates.\\
           Cheaper than other A-frame racks}
            & {Not stackable\\
               Space-saving compared to storing doors in crates.\\
               Cheaper than other A-frame racks}
                &       \\
% SECOND ROW
\includegraphics{images/myLboro.png}
    & {configuration: Vertical\\
       Dimensions: At least one-third of the product height should rest against the divider.\\
       The V-Divider depth dimension: \qty{4}{ft}}
        & {Bulk doors stored vertically within a bay.\\
           Facilitates one part picking.\\
           Cheaper than buying new racks.}
            & {Add door fixtures to secure doors at the bottom to timber decking or rack mesh.\\
               Dividers to divide 8 different P/N.\\
               Labeling locations per dividers.}
                &       \\
% THIRD ROW
\includegraphics{images/myLboro.png}
    & {Configuration: Horizontally on the bars\\
       Dimensions: \qtyproduct{16 x 26 x 24}{''} }
        & {Capacity: \qty{7,500}{LBS}
           Stackable up to five units high
           Unit cost: \qty{115.96}{\$}
           Space needed per unit: \qty{4.3}{sq,ft}}
            & NO CONS
                &       \\
% FOURTH ROW  (repeated third), IF EXIST
\includegraphics{images/myLboro.png}
    & {Configuration: Horizontally on the bars\\
       Dimensions: \qtyproduct{16 x 26 x 24}{''} }
        & {Capacity: \qty{7,500}{LBS}
           Stackable up to five units high
           Unit cost: \qty{115.96}{\$}
           Space needed per unit: \qty{4.3}{sq,ft}}
            & NO CONS
                &       \\
   \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
If you like add a caption to the table, then in the above solution, you need to remove options, which remove the caption from the table and add a caption which you like to have. See MWE below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, demo]{report}  % in real document remove "demo"
\usepackage[hmargin={3.81cm, 2.54cm}, top=3.175cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export,
            demo]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\section{Proposed storage solutions}
Based on the current packaging and storage issues, the following solutions were proposed after brainstorming:
\begingroup
\setkeys{Gin}{width=20mm, height=60mm}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Caption},     % <---
  label = {tab:long?}    % <---
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {c *{3}{X[h, l]} c},
                  colsep  = {4pt},
                  column{1} = {colsep=3pt},
                  row{1}  = {font=\small\bfseries, c, m},
                  row{2-Z} = {belowsep+=-4pt},
                  rowhead = 1,
                  }
Solution
    & Specifications
        & Pros
            & Cons
                & {Total\\ cost}    \\
% table body
% FIRST ROW
\includegraphics{images/myLboro.png}
    & {Configuration: Vertical\\
       Stability: Tension clamp with pressure plate\\
       Dimensions: \qtyproduct{48 x 40 x 65}{''}
       Capacity: \qty{661}{pounds}}
        & {Easy to assemble/ dismantle the rack.\\
           Space-saving compared to storing doors in crates.\\
           Cheaper than other A-frame racks}
            & {Not stackable\\
               Space-saving compared to storing doors in crates.\\
               Cheaper than other A-frame racks}
                &       \\
% SECOND ROW
\includegraphics{images/myLboro.png}
    & {configuration: Vertical\\
       Dimensions: At least one-third of the product height should rest against the divider.\\
       The V-Divider depth dimension: \qty{4}{ft}}
        & {Bulk doors stored vertically within a bay.\\
           Facilitates one part picking.\\
           Cheaper than buying new racks.}
            & {Add door fixtures to secure doors at the bottom to timber decking or rack mesh.\\
               Dividers to divide 8 different P/N.\\
               Labeling locations per dividers.}
                &       \\
% THIRD ROW
\includegraphics{images/myLboro.png}
    & {Configuration: Horizontally on the bars\\
       Dimensions: \qtyproduct{16 x 26 x 24}{''} }
        & {Capacity: \qty{7,500}{LBS}
           Stackable up to five units high
           Unit cost: \qty{115.96}{\$}
           Space needed per unit: \qty{4.3}{sq,ft}}
            & NO CONS
                &       \\
% FOURTH ROW  (repeated third), IF EXIST
\includegraphics{images/myLboro.png}
    & {Configuration: Horizontally on the bars\\
       Dimensions: \qtyproduct{16 x 26 x 24}{''} }
        & {Capacity: \qty{7,500}{LBS}
           Stackable up to five units high
           Unit cost: \qty{115.96}{\$}
           Space needed per unit: \qty{4.3}{sq,ft}}
            & NO CONS
                &       \\
   \end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: I wonder if you really need so height image. Reducing their height, for example, by 10%  enable a better fit table on the first page. For this change `\setkeys{Gin}{width=20mm, height=60mm}` to `\setkeys{Gin}{width=20mm, height=55mm}`

Comment: Technicallym, it replace both table (for captions) and tabular.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: How can I add caption to this type of table?

Comment: @MohamedAzizTousli, original answer has caption but han I see that your table in question doesn't has it. I will show, where is caption in `longtblt` ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the  itemize environment and I get only one page:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw}{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[left=3.81cm, right=2.54cm, top=3.175cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor,array}
\hbadness=99999 

\begin{document}
    
\section{Proposed storage solutions}
Based on the current packaging and storage issues the following solutions were proposed after brainstorming:

\noindent\small 
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|X|X|X|p{0.1\linewidth}|}\hline
            % HEADER ROW
\textbf{Solution} & \textbf{Specifications} & \textbf{Pros} & \textbf{Cons} & \textbf{Total   cost} \\ \hline           
            % FIRST ROW
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\totalheight+\normalbaselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=60mm]{images/myLboro.png}}            
            & Configuration: Vertical\newline
              Stability: Tension clamp with pressure plate\newline
              Dimensions: 48’’x 40 x 65’’\newline
              Capacity: 661 pounds
            & Easy to assemble/ dismantle the rack.\newline
              Space-saving compared to storing doors in crates.\newline
              Cheaper than other A-frame racks
            & Not stackable\newline
              Space-saving compared to storing doors in crates.\newline
              Cheaper than other A-frame racks
            &  \\ \hline
            
            % SECOND ROW
            \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=60mm]{images/myLboro.png}}
            
            &
            \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
                \item[] configuration: Vertical 
                \item[] Dimensions: At least one-third of the product height should rest against the divider. The V-Divider depth dimension= 4 ft
            \end{itemize}
            
            & 
            \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
                \item[] Bulk doors stored vertically within a bay.
                \item[] Facilitates one part picking.
                \item[] Cheaper than buying new racks.
            \end{itemize}
            
            & 
            \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
                \item[] Add door fixtures to secure doors at the bottom to timber decking or rack mesh.
                \item[] Dividers to divide 8 different P/N.
                \item[] Labeling locations per dividers.
            \end{itemize}
            
            &  \\ \hline
            
            % THIRD ROW
            \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=60mm]{images/myLboro.png}}
            
            & 
            \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
                \item[] Configuration: Horizontally on the bars 
                \item[] Dimensions:16"W x 26"L x 24"H 
            \end{itemize}
            & 
            \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
                \item[] Capacity: 7,500 LBS
                \item[] Stackable up to five units high
                \item[] Unit cost: 115.96 \$
                \item[] Space needed per unit: 4.3 sq,ft

            \end{itemize}
            &  
            \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=0pt]
                \item[] NO CONS
            \end{itemize}           
            &  \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

\normalsize
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`longtable` is no substitute for `table`.

Your table is too wide, so I set it sticking out of both margins. Please, read the manual for the other parts I added.

Instead of `\raisebox` you can employ the `valign` key provided by `adjustbox`.

For the `itemize` lists, I believe it's better to use item separation or the table would be very hard to read. Also, in order to reduce the width I used `\footnotesize`.

Just to see that the table splits properly across pages, I repeated the third row.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,draft]{report}
\usepackage[left=3.81cm, right=2.54cm, top=3.175cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\section{Proposed storage solutions}
Based on the current packaging and storage issues the following solutions 
were proposed after brainstorming:

\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt minus 300pt}
\setlength{\LTright}{0pt minus 300pt}
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{
  |>{\raggedright}p{0.2\textwidth}|
   >{\raggedright}p{0.22\textwidth}|
   >{\raggedright}p{0.22\textwidth}|
   >{\raggedright}p{0.22\textwidth}|
   >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.14\textwidth}|
}
\hline
% HEADER ROW
\textbf{Solution} &
\textbf{Specifications} &
\textbf{Pros} &
\textbf{Cons} &
\textbf{Total cost} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
% FIRST ROW
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=60mm,valign=T]{images/myLboro.png} &
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,label={},leftmargin=0pt]
  \item Configuration: Vertical
  \item Stability: Tension clamp with pressure plate
  \item Dimensions: 48’’x 40 x 65’’
  \item Capacity: 661 pounds
\end{itemize} & 
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,label={},leftmargin=0pt]
  \item Easy to assemble/ dismantle the rack.
  \item Space-saving compared to storing doors in crates.
  \item Cheaper than other A-frame racks
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,label={},leftmargin=0pt]
  \item Not stackable
  \item Space-saving compared to storing doors in crates.
  \item Cheaper than other A-frame racks
\end{itemize} &
\\ \hline
% SECOND ROW
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=60mm,valign=T]{images/myLboro.png} &
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,label={},leftmargin=0pt]
  \item configuration: Vertical 
  \item Dimensions: At least one-third of the product height should rest against the divider. The V-Divider depth dimension= 4 ft
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,label={},leftmargin=0pt]
  \item Bulk doors stored vertically within a bay.
  \item Facilitates one part picking.
  \item Cheaper than buying new racks.
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,label={},leftmargin=0pt]
  \item Add door fixtures to secure doors at the bottom to timber decking or rack mesh.
  \item Dividers to divide 8 different P/N.
  \item Labeling locations per dividers.
\end{itemize} &
\\ \hline
% THIRD ROW
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=60mm,valign=T]{images/myLboro.png} & 
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,label={},leftmargin=0pt]
  \item Configuration: Horizontally on the bars 
  \item Dimensions:16"W x 26"L x 24"H 
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,label={},leftmargin=0pt]
  \item Capacity: 7,500 LBS
  \item Stackable up to five units high
  \item Unit cost: 115.96 \$
  \item Space needed per unit: 4.3 sq,ft
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,label={},leftmargin=0pt]
  \item NO CONS
\end{itemize} &
\\ \hline
% THIRD ROW (repeated)
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=60mm,valign=T]{images/myLboro.png} & 
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,label={},leftmargin=0pt]
  \item Configuration: Horizontally on the bars 
  \item Dimensions:16"W x 26"L x 24"H 
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,label={},leftmargin=0pt]
  \item Capacity: 7,500 LBS
  \item Stackable up to five units high
  \item Unit cost: 115.96 \$
  \item Space needed per unit: 4.3 sq,ft
\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,label={},leftmargin=0pt]
  \item NO CONS
\end{itemize} &
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.